# How to generate an ECDH key in VB.net with an HSM provider

Tags: vb.net, hsm, ecdh

I'm trying to use an HSM provider when generating a CngKey in vb.net, to do ECDH.

'provider' is correctly set (I can do other things, ie generate an AES key and use it).

If I pre-generate the key using the HSMs native tools, the Exists() returns true, but when I try to use it, the HSM responds with "this operation is not supported".  This may either be that it isn't supported (Docs say it is, however), OR it is not supported via CngKey because it's doing something unexpected but .net (.Net is not supported natively/there is no .NET provider), OR I've not generated a suitable key.

To test whether it's a key metadata problem (usage, etc), I'm trying to use CngKey.Create to generate the key with the provider:

```
    Dim key As CngKey = Nothing
    Dim keyExists As Boolean = CngKey.Exists(keyName, provider)
    If Not keyExists Then
        Dim keyCreationParameters = New CngKeyCreationParameters()
        keyCreationParameters.Provider = provider
        keyCreationParameters.ExportPolicy = CngExportPolicies.AllowExport
        keyCreationParameters.KeyUsage = CngKeyUsages.KeyAgreement
        Try
            CngKey.Create(New CngAlgorithm("ECDiffieHellmanP521"), keyName, keyCreationParameters)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Button1.Text = ex.Message
            Return
        End Try
    End If
    ' open the key (I can open the pre-generated key and get a key handle
    ' but then it fails later when I try to use it):
    Using alice As New ECDiffieHellmanCng(serverKeyPair) ' serverKeyPair is the handle
```

throws
System.ArgumentException "Keys used ... must have an algorithm group of ECDiffieHellman"

and the provider log just says that "Algorithm Group" is empty.

Assumptions:

1. Querent last worked in VB when it was Windows 3.1.  It's ... moved on.

So if the above is flat out "that's not how you do it', show, don't tell, because I probably won't understand the tell.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line:

```
CngKey.Create(New CngAlgorithm("ECDiffieHellmanP521"), keyName, keyCreationParameters)
```

I don't know if this is a Windows thing, a VB.net thing, or a Provider thing.

```
CngKey.Create(CngAlgorithm.ECDiffieHellmanP521, keyName, keyCreationParameters)
```

Maybe someone can comment.